# Ordering all $N!$ permutations in a way that maximize "positional movements"

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Apologies in advance that this is not a fully well-defined question...

In my work group of $N=8$ people, we have a daily meeting ("scrum") where everyone talks for a minute about their work.  We used to do this alphabetically, until someone wants some variety so Anthony doesn't always go first and Zac always last.

Right now we're trying to alternate alphabetical and reverse-alphabetic.  But this leads me to ponder a math question:  **Is there a way to somehow "maximize" people's "positional movements" from one day to the next?**

E.g. if we alternate alphabetical vs reverse-alphabetical, then Anthony and Zac had the maximum positional movement (from $1$ to $8$, vice versa) from one day to the next, but the $4$th-place and $5$th-place people just had a positional movement of $1$ from one day to the next.  Ideally I want to maximize the positional movements not just in sum, but also spread them over different people.

Let $\sigma_t$ be the permutation on day $t$.  Define the positional movement for person $i$ from day $t$ to day $t+1$ as $\Delta_t(i) = |\sigma_t(i) - \sigma_{t+1}(i)|$.

Assume that the set $\{\sigma_t | 1 \le t \le 8!\} =$ the set of all possible permutations, and further that $\sigma_t = \sigma_{t + 8!}$ i.e. the cycle repeats.  Here are some quantities that (I think) seem related to what I (vaguely) want.  Would these be the right thing to maximize, and if so, how?

(A) $\sum_{1 \le t \le 8!} \sum_{1 \le i \le 8} \Delta_t(i) = $ simple sum of all movements

(B) $\sum_{1 \le t \le 8!} \min_{1 \le i \le 8} \Delta_t(i) = $ sum of each day's worst (smallest) movement

(C) $\min_{1 \le i \le 8} \sum_{1 \le t \le 8!} \Delta_t(i) = $ the least-moved person's total movement

(D) $\min_{1 \le i \le 8} \min_{1 \le t \le 8!} \Delta_t(i) = $ the globally smallest movement

Again, sorry this is vague and not well-formed.  If people have ideas on the appropriateness and ease-of-maximization of the above, or any other suggestions, that'd be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It is indeed good to point out that there are *many* ways of defining a score to an ordering of the permutations, and I think this is an interesting problem. However, none of your proposals explicitly takes into account how far a fixed pair of people is away from eachother in consecutive days. Does this matter to you?
Also, my intuition says that perhaps it will be easier to minimize $(\Delta_t(i))^2$.

Comment: Thanks @Steven - I never thought about your ideas and they are interesting, esp. a fixed pair's distance to each other.  Obviously, they make the problem even more complicated (and interesting); OTOH if you have good ideas how to solve/approach your variants I'd enjoy hearing about those ideas!